# How to make alternate li bold?

Tags: css

In a ul li list , how to make an alternate li bold. Like shown in the image.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: If the answer was helpful please do upvote it.

Comment: vote up require 15 reputation. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [nth-child(even)](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd) pseudo selector:

```
li:nth-child(even) {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Use odd or even depending on whether you want the first one bold.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A3a2U/) on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this

```
ul li:nth-child(odd)
{
font-weight:bold;
}
```

**[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pySuG/)**

**Note:***If you want to start from first li element then use odd if you want to start from second element then use even as alexn suggests in his answer.*